# Publish NetCore 2.2 on IIS from Linux

Tags: jenkins, iis, continuous-integration, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

I know there is an open issue to make msdeploy cross-platform (https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/583). But I would like to know if there is any workaround deploy a NetCore application in a Windows IIS machine from Linux.

I have a CentOS jenkins-agent that does the dotnet build, dotnet test and then dotnet publish. In a Windows agent I would call MSDeploy, but I don't have one. How to approach this?

Comment: Like that thread indicates, the easiest is to build a Docker image out, and then launch it like any other Docker images. What else do you want?

Comment: @LexLi I have a Windows Server machine with lots of applications already using this IIS. I need to launch the application in the same IIS. I don't see how a docker image would fit in this case. Do you suggest me to launch a Windows image inside the Linux agent and use it's msdeploy?

Comment: A Windows Server today (depending on the version you use) should be capable of hosting Docker images as first class citizens, and .NET Core also naturally supports that feature from its day 1. MSDeploy was designed solely with Windows/IIS in mind, so I am not surprised to see nothing has been done in that thread.

Comment: @LexLi the problem is bigger than that. I know I could host a docker image in my Windows Server. But my netcore application is part of a legacy portal that uses IIS filters, so the application needs as a requirement to run inside the same IIS as the rest of the portal.

Comment: @LexLi Surely, if I was prepared to change my environment so much as to install the entire Docker infrastructure on my Windows server… I'd just put it on a Linux server!

Comment: And come to think of it, the reason I haven't put my server on linux yet is that I can't manage to make my Linux servers connect to my SQL Server database with Windows Authentication — which would still be a problem with a docker container in Windows!

Answer (score -1):

Use up to dotnet -publish and copy to the desired folder. Pre-copy the file appofline and delete it after.

Comment: Sounds right... but this is StackOverflow: please provide an example. Frankly, I'm not at all sure **which** files need to be copied.